# C: XNOR / Exclusive-Nor gate?

Tags: c, logic, xor

I am trying to find the most effective way of writing a XNOR gate in C.

```
if(VAL1 XNOR VAL2)
{
    BLOCK;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

With two operands this is quite simple:

```
if (val1 == val2)
{
    block;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Sometimes, we tend to look away from the most obvious things!

Comment: This answer is incorrect as it assumes the two values are equal. What if they are both non-zero but different values?

Answer (score 7):

```
if(!(val1^val2))
{
    block;
}
```

edit: outside of logical operations, you'd probably want `~(val1^val2)` to be exact, but i find the ! clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `val1` and `val2` are to be treated in the normal C logical boolean fashion (non-zero is true), then:

```
if (!val1 ^ !!val2)
{

}
```

will do the trick.